# How to build a Uri in Spray?

Tags: scala, spray

I would like to make a simple `GET` request via Spray with a few query parameters

```
Get("http://localhost/user?email=abc+a@abc.com")
```

However `+` means a space in application/x-www-form-urlencoded content resulting the call to `http://localhost/user?email=abc a@abc.com` (with a space instead of plus sign).

I could use a non-Spray `java.net.URLEncoder` to encode the URL before passing it to the GET request however I doing this every time seems like a hack.

Is there a Spray way of applying query parameters and encoding them?

`Uri("http://localhost/").withQuery(Map("email"->"abc+a@abc.com"))` is a nice way to construct a Uri but it doesn't encode the params as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `Uri("http://localhost/").withQuery(Map("email"->"abc+a@abc.com"))` works fine as it encodes the special symbols.

However, `Uri("http://localhost/").withQuery("email=abc+a@abc.com")` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I use java.net.URLEncoder. I believe that is the accepted method.
It would be nice if that happened automatically!